# How to expand multiple UICollectionViewCells on tap

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to build a collectionView that can expand multiple cells after they've been selected/tapped or collapsed when they are deselected, everything works fine when the cells remain on the screen, but once the expanded cells go off screen, I get unexpected behaviour.

For example if I select a cell with IndexPath 0 and then scroll down, tap on cell with IndexPath of 8, scroll back to cell with IndexPath 0 (it's already collapsed), I would tap on it and scroll back to the cell with IndexPath 8 and tap on it again it expands + cell with IndexPath 10 would expand too.

The CollectionView has been implemented programmatically as well the UICollectionViewCell has been subclassed.

ViewController that holds the UICollectionView:

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties
    fileprivate var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var manipulateIndex: NSIndexPath? {
        didSet {
            collectionView.reloadItems(at: collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems!)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource
extension CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 13
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.textLabel.text = "\(indexPath.item)"
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

        return cell
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate
extension CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.expanded = !cell.expanded

        manipulateIndex = indexPath as NSIndexPath

        return false
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
extension CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell {
            if cell.expanded == true {
                return CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width - 20, height: 300)
            }

            if cell.expanded == false {
                return CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width - 20, height: 120.0)
            }
        }

        return CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width - 20, height: 120.0)

    }
}
```

And the subclassed custom UICollectionViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var expanded: Bool = false
    var textLabel: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        textLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height/3))
        textLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.smallSystemFontSize)
        textLabel.textAlignment = .center
        contentView.addSubview(textLabel)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Please help and thank you so much to the amazing person, who can help me out! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: 
**Example 1: Expand only one cell at a time** 
Note: No need to take expanded bool variable in custom cell

```
var section:Int?
var preSection:Int?
var expand:Bool = false


extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 13
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.textLabel.text = "\(indexPath.item)"
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if (self.section != nil) {
            self.preSection = self.section
        }

        self.section = indexPath.row

        if self.preSection == self.section {
            self.preSection = nil
            self.section = nil
        }else if (self.preSection != nil) {
            self.expand = false
        }
        self.expand = !self.expand
        self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems!)

    }

}


// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        if self.expand, let row = self.section, row == indexPath.row {
            return CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width - 20, height: 300)
        }else{
            return CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width - 20, height: 120.0)
        }

    }
}
```

**Example 2:
Expand multiple cell**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    // MARK: - Properties
    fileprivate var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var expandSection = [Bool]()
    var items = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.items = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","J","K"]
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.expandSection = [Bool](repeating: false, count: self.items.count)

        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.textLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        self.expandSection[indexPath.row] = !self.expandSection[indexPath.row]
        self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems!)
    }

}


// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        if self.expandSection[indexPath.row] {
            return CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width - 20, height: 300)
        }else{
            return CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width - 20, height: 120.0)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UICollectionView will reuse your cells for multiple objects in your data model.  You can't control which cells get reused when during `reloadItems` You should not assume that the `expanded` state in a given cell corresponds to the state of your data model.  Instead, you should be holding onto the `expanded` state somehow in your data model and re-setting that in every call to `cellForItemAt`.

In other words, hold your state in your model and set the cell state in `cellForItemAt`, don't hold it in the cells themselves.